# iOS TabBarController shows only black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a TabBarController with 4 UIViewControllers. However, when I want to show one of the ViewControllers in the TabBarController with:

```
func gotoMainAppVC()
{
    let mainVC:SearchVC = SearchVC()
    self.present(mainVC, animated: true, completion:  nil)
}
```

I only get a plain black screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is searchVC your tab bar controller? Is your tabbarcontroller created through storyboard?

Comment: Add some more details...

Comment: No, searchVC is one of the UIViewControllers that corresponds to the tabs. The TabBarController itself is created in the Storyboard, not in the code

Comment: `present(animated:)` should present view controller modally (by default).  I suppos it's not what you want. Take a look on manual related to UITabBarController  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller

Comment: PS: usually there is no need to subclass UITabBarController, as it is just a container, controller. I advice to to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how any of this works.

I am not sure what `self` is in your context but I expect it is either a tab bar controller or one of the view controllers on the tab bar.

By calling `present` it means you want to present a view controller on a current one which by default brings a new fullscreen view controller from bottom upwards.

Since you have created a new instance of view controller by calling `SearchVC()` this is not the view controller that you see in your storyboard. You may create any instances of any of your view controllers but in your case if you designed `SearchVC` in a storyboard you want to actually use that version of it. To do so you need to set storyboard id inside your storyboard. After you have done that you should initialise it as using:

```
UIStoryboard(name: <#T##String#>, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: <#T##String#>)
```

as in

```
let mainVC:SearchVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TheIDIHaveSet") as! SearchVC
```

But again this will not give you the view controller that is inside your tab bar but create a new instance. And it will not instert it as one of the tabs but present a new full screen view controller.

Comment: Thanks! So what would be the best way to show the tab bar controller?

Comment: @erdwfddsfdfsdfsdffd I would need more information about that. Now you are saying to show tab bar controller, in question it seemed like a specific view controller inside a tab bar which is already visible.